# test if jpg file exists in other domino database

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'd like to make a fallback when displaying pictures out of a notes database.
The notes database normally contains a pdf and a jpg version with the same name (except the extension)
If the jpg picture exists I would like to display it , if not I would like to display the pdf using google drive

```
return "<embed src='https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://demourl.pdf' width='500' height='375'></embed>"
```

So the question is : what's the best way to test if a picture exists in a notes document

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: @Per Henrik In javascript there's something like "file.exists()"  , but I don't get that to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view showing all design elements and then do a lookup if the required picture is contained in the database.

Here is the required Lotus Script Code to modify a view for displaying all design elements in a NSF:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim view As NotesView
Dim doc As NotesDocument

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set view = db.GetView("DesignElements")
Set doc = db.GetDocumentByUNID(view.UniversalID)
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("$FormulaClass","32766")
Call doc.Save(True,True)
```

Just add a sorted column for "$TITLE".

**EDIT:**

Shameless copied from https://www.assono.de/blog/ye118wday-design-elements-views

**EDIT 2:**
If you just want to check for a existence of a file in a normal document, I suggest to create a view with two sorted columns. 1st column with DocumentUNID, 2nd with @AttachmentNames-Formula. Then you can do a lookup for the specific document / attachment.

Comment: This seems to show all files that are in the nsf. I'm looking for a way to find out if a document (knowing the uind) in the nsf contains a certain file , before opening it Probably my question wasn't clear.

Comment: @Sven I did it like in your second edit. The only thing I had was that the pictures were added like pictures , not as attachments and then don't appear in the column with AttachmentNames. I could solve that , so thank you